# Why is there a comma after who?

Tags: sentence-construction, commas

This textbook says,

> "The San Francisco School Department was sued on behalf of Chinese
> speaking students who, parents and other advocates charged, were not
> being provided with an equal education".

Usually, comma is before "who" but this one is after.
Why is this correct?

Comment: There are 'parenthetical' commas before and after the parenthetical clause 'parents and other advocates charged'. This is correct.

Comment: One way to test for this is to remove the part of the sentence that is inside the commas and see if it still makes sense.  So that would be: "The San Francisco School Department was sued on behalf of Chinese speaking students who were not being provided with an equal education."  The "parenthetical" adds some additional detail but doesn't change the original information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *parents and other advocates charged* is a parenthesis, separated from the main sentence by commas. The main sentence refers to *Chinese-speaking students who were not being provided with an equal education.*